# SharePoint 2013 workflows manual invoking throwing error

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

In SharePoint 2013 Designer workflows, workflows throwing error when started workflow manually. below is the error

> w3wp.exe (0x06D6) 0x1F3C SharePoint Foundation General 8nca Medium
>   Application error when access /_layouts/15/Workflow.aspx, Error=Method
>   ‘StartWorkflowOnListItem’ in type
>   ‘Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowInstanceProvider’
>   from assembly ‘Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices,
>   Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c’
>   does not have an implementation. at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricSolutionProviderFactory….
>
> w3wp.exe (0x06D6) 0x1F3C SharePoint Foundation Runtime tkau Unexpected
>   System.TypeLoadException: Method ‘StartWorkflowOnListItem’ in type
>   ‘Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricWorkflowInstanceProvider’
>   from assembly ‘Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices,
>   Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c’
>   does not have an implementation. at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricSolutionProviderFactory.<.cctor>b__3(WorkflowServicesContext
>   context) at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.FabricSolutionProviderFactory.GetProvider[T]…

Based on the below blogs, we have installed patches in DEV instance Single Tier working fine and in the same way we have updated in the PROD which having one Web Front End Server, Search Server and Database server.

Updated these patches in both WFE and Search server, but no luck, issue did not resolved in PROD.

- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29100.after-installing-sharepoint-2013-service-pack-1-or-higher-update-workflow-service-stops-working.aspx
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/bc32f931-d304-40ae-b84a-7c70208b1689/sharepoint-2013-clicking-on-list-item-workflows-link-returns-error?forum=sharepointadmin

Kindly help here to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Do you use WF 2010 or WF 2013, أ Have you installed the Workflow Manager?!

Comment: Thanks for the comments, We are using WF 2010 template, WF 2013 templates are not enabled.                                                                        Workflow Manager was installed in App Server  "Workflow Manager 1.0" and "Workflow Manager Client 1.0"  both installed

Answer (score 0):

Determine whether the update is installed on all SharePoint servers and it is installed successfully.

The update contains the files are listed in the [this KB 2880963 article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2880963).

Run IISRESET on servers, see if it works.